# Unexplainable error (Segm.fault 11) with gcc4.2.1

Tags: c, gcc

I have a **really** simple program, but it doesn't work. Furthermore, it gives me severe doubts about the flow of the program.

The program is  like this(assuming necessary headers):

```
main(){
printf("hello1");
printf("hello2");
somefunction();
}
```

The output is peculiar at the least: It gives me back just the first printf(hello1), immediately afterwards the program quits with error "Segmentation fault 11". **However**, if I delete 'somefunction()' the second printf is **ALSO** shown.

I mean, if there is some problem with my 'somefunction()', the second printf() should regardless be shown.

Answer (score 5):

Your `somefunction` does something nasty and the process is killed before `printf` has the chance to flush the buffer. You can try:

```
printf("hello1");
printf("hello2");
fflush(stdout);
somefunction();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. Now I can try debugging somefunction.

Answer (score 2):

stdout is line buffered. This means that your output is buffered somewhere to be printed later, but since you `somefunction` crashes, it doesn't get the chance to print them.

You can either flush the buffer using `fflush`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Or, print a new line:

```
main(){
    printf("hello1\n");
    printf("hello2\n");
    somefunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should always put a `\n` at the end of print statements, unless you know exactly what you are doing. This will ensure that the statement actually makes it to the output.

```
printf("hello1\n");
printf("hello2\n");
somefunction();
```